# constant index passed to event handler in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I am having trouble processing an event handler in my D3 code: before refactoring, it was working as intended:

```
choice_groups
  .append("span")
  .attr("class", "repeat-choice")
  .text("Modifica questa scelta")
  .on("click", repeat_choice);
```

the repeat_choice() function was called with the index i parameter of the span.repeat-choice element clicked.

Since i only want to attach this event handler to elements which have more than one nested data elements, i refactored the above code like this:

```
choice_groups
  .each(function(d, i) {
    if(d.length > 1) {
      d3.select(this)
        .append("span")
        .attr("class", "repeat-choice")
        .text("Modifica questa scelta")
        .on("click", repeat_choice);
    } else {
      d3.select(this)
        .append("span")
        .attr("class", "no-choice")
        .html("&nbsp;");
    }
  });
```

However, the repeat_choice() handler function now always gets invoked with i=0, no matter which is the index of the element that is clicked.

I guess I am not using selection.each() correctly: the resulting markup is as expected (and as before refactoring), only the click handler function does not get passed the element's index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inner d3.select() is creating a new selection and therefore resetting i=0 (in the context of that selection) each time. You could conditionally set the attributes:

```
choice_groups
  .append("span")
  .attr("class", function(d,i) { return d.length > 1 ? "repeat-choice" : "no-choice"; })
  .text(function(d,i) { return d.length > 1 ? "Modifica questa scelta" : null; });
```

or maybe reselect only the "repeat-choice" elements and bind the click handling later:

```
choice_groups
    .filter(function(d,i){ return d.length > 1;})
    .on("click", repeat_choice);
```

(the i passed to repeat_choice will count only the filtered elements in this second selection as well, I think)

Hope that helps.